# Is there a way to conbine jQuery .click functions to increase browser speed/reduce lag?

Tags: jquery

I've got a bunch of button/dropdown pairs. When the button is hovered over, I want to animate its paired dropdown.  Here's what I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dropdown-link#hover0").click(function () {
            $(".dropdown0").toggle("easeInOutQuint");
        });
        $(".dropdown-link#hover1").click(function () {
            $(".dropdown1").toggle("easeInOutQuint");
        });
        $(".dropdown-link#hover2").click(function () {
            $(".dropdown2").toggle("easeInOutQuint");
        });
        $(".dropdown-link#hover3").click(function () {
            $(".dropdown3").toggle("easeInOutQuint");
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/pzw7y35a/

But I've got lots of them, and manually linking each in this manner is really inefficient.  Is there a way to find the dropdown that is paired with the button, so I can add the click handler to all at once?

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient?" It works.  Are they not dropping down fast enough?

Comment: Ehh,...just remove the ID and target the class.

Comment: maybe what he mean that any way to make it shorten?

Comment: `->` http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i mean instead if defining ever dropdown can a code choose the nearest .dropdown to the button and not open all of them.

Comment: @Timothy: Yes. Look at the traversal methods at your disposal: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/, http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/. You can use those methods to find the corresponding `.dropdown` element.

Comment: Question is too broad, what do you mean more efficient? In what way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say this is a little "shorter", it's the only type of efficiency I see you can improve on your code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropdown-link").click(function () {
        $(this).next().toggle("easeInOutQuint");
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/claudioredi/ca9xLvbo/)

Comment: Or `$('#hover0, #hover1, ...').each(...)`, or even just `$('.dropdown-link[id^=hover]').each(...)`.

Comment: @Timothy: forget about that one, check the second one ;)

Comment: @Timothy: That's called ["string concatenation"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators). E.g. `"foo" + 3` results in the string `"foo3"`.

Comment: @Claudio Redi: Wow that's really simple. thats 1/10 of my original code XD.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".dropdownlink[id^=hover]").function() {
    var index = this.id.substr(5); // ID is hoverINDEX
    $(".dropdown" + index).toggle("easeInOutQuint");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way to

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
(function(index) {
$("#hover" + index).click(function () {
$(".dropdown" + index).toggle("easeInOutQuint");
});
})(i);}
```